# How can I go about implementing a simple react drag and drop feature

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement a simple drag and drop feature in react using react-beautiful-dnd library, however, I'm getting this error "children is not a function
TypeError: children is not a function".
Or is there another simpler library that I can use?

draggable component:

```
  const [isDragging, setIsDragging] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Droppable droppableId="task-list">
      {(provided) => (
        <Draggable
          draggableId={id}
          isDragging={isDragging}
          onDragStart={() => setIsDragging(true)}
          onDragEnd={() => setIsDragging(false)}
          {...provided.droppableProps}
        >
          <Card style={{ marginBottom: "15px" }}>
            {(props) => (
              <Card {...props}>
                <CardContent>
                  <h4>{name}</h4>
                  <p>{description}</p>
                </CardContent>
              </Card>
            )}
          </Card>
        </Draggable>
      )}
    </Droppable>
  );
```

Droppable component:

```
  return (
    <Card className={classes.cont}>
      <CardHeader
        title={title}
        action={
          <IconButton>
            <MoreVertIcon />
          </IconButton>
        }
      />
      <hr />
      <CardContent>
        <div>
          {tasks.map((task) => (
            <Droppable
              droppableId={task.id}
              isDragging={isDragging}
              onDragEnter={() => {
                setIsDragging(true);
              }}
              onDragLeave={() => {
                setIsDragging(false);
              }}
              onDrop={(result) => {
                // Do something with the result of the drop event.
                console.log("dropped here", result);
              }}
            >
              {(provided) => (
                <Draggable
                  draggableId={task.id}
                  {...provided.droppableProps}
                  task={task}
                >
                  <TaskCard key={task.id} />
                </Draggable>
              )}
            </Droppable>
          ))}
        </div>
      </CardContent>
      <hr />
      <CardContent>Button</CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
```

Please assist

Comment: You seem passing a Draggable component directly as a child of the Droppable component instead of using a render prop?

Answer (score 0):

here's a simple example of a React app with drag and drop functionality for a list of items using the HTML5 drag and drop API:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

const initialItems = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Item 1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Item 2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Item 3' },
];

function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(initialItems);

  const handleDragStart = (e, item) => {
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', JSON.stringify(item));
  };

  const handleDrop = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const droppedItem = JSON.parse(e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain'));
    const updatedItems = items.filter((item) => item.id !== droppedItem.id);
    setItems([...updatedItems, droppedItem]);
  };

  const handleDragOver = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div
        className="drop-target"
        onDrop={handleDrop}
        onDragOver={handleDragOver}
      >
        Drop items here:
        {items.map((item) => (
          <div
            key={item.id}
            className="draggable-item"
            draggable
            onDragStart={(e) => handleDragStart(e, item)}
          >
            {item.name}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

App.css file for styling

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.drop-target {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px dashed #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.draggable-item {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```